# What does "export >/dev/stderr" mean?

Tags: bash, shell, stderr

I've found in a bash script following line:

```
export >/dev/stderr
```

what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is meant to print the environment somewhere else than in stdout, probably because the output will be piped to another program or in a file.
What I don't know is why it uses the command `export` and not `env`.
But maybe the script is much more complex than that and reads or even executes the content of stderr, anyway stderr is meant as I said to print some output while it being ignored by redirectors or pipes.